# "Easy way" to convert existing Wordpress website to Android/IOS App

Tags: java, android, ios, wordpress, kotlin

I've been looking into this for a while and i just want to know if some experienced devs can list the options i have.

Basically what I need is to convert a Wordpress website with all it's plugins to mobile Android/IOS application. No additions, just as is.
I know there are lot of plugins that offer to do that. however **I'd like to know my options**

The app is basically the same as the website with the exact same functions, just accessed via the app icon.

Is there an easy way to "show" a website on an app? like passing the link, or using the app as some sort of browser maybe?

**What are my options?**

Answer (score 1):

The best what you can do is you can use PWA which will wrap your Wordpress website and create App launch icon easily. You have existing plugins even in Wordpress, that's what I've found:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/progressive-wp/

Another plus is that you can later add support for offline mode, notifications etc.

Comment: So this makes your WP-website basically a PWA. Cool, but how would i convert that into an Android Application?

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by Android Application - native android app, android app you can install from Google Play Store, app with some additional capabilities?

Comment: For example on Android you can treat PWA almost like native app in terms of installing it from Google Play Store, functionalities etc. Maybe if you have some heavy GPU operations I would consider native, but this solution in my opinion is best in terms of costs/quality

Comment: As i said the Android App is supposed to be exactly the same as the WP-website. All the plug-ins should also work. No additional capabilities.Just the exact same site on the Play Store.

Comment: Okay, so use PWA to have WP website as Android App

Comment: Okay, but can you explain it a bit more? So you're saying i should install the PWA-plugin you've linked on my WP website, Then what? I fail to understand how this will get me an app on the Play Store.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223735/discussion-between-user10515430-and-mariusz-brona).